# Determining if a source file unportably relies on indirect includes of standard headers

Tags: c++, include, header-files

Let's say I have a `file.cpp` which includes several C++ header files and uses various functions and classes from the standard library. It may be that I am using some functionality which comes from a header file that I don't directly include, but is indirectly included by some *other* standard library header file that I included. That's an unintentional programming error, but everything will compile and work fine on my platform, due to the indirect include.

Not only is the program ill-formed, there is no guarantee that other platforms will have the same indirect includes, so the code may fail to compile on that other platform and this is common in practice.

Is there any automated way to check for "missing includes" of this type, where I can't just rely on the compile failing on my platform because of the indirect includes?

As a specific example, in gcc's libc++5 the `<memory>` header includes a bunch of other standard library headers, such as `<functional>`, but that's not true on other versions of the compiler and other compilers. So if I use something from `<functional>` I won't get a compiler error, but other users might...

Comment: The easier way would be to create fake system headers with only required declarations, and use that instead in the tool chain... You will got compilation error in case of bad include. and finally linker error once all include are correct.

Comment: @Jarod42 That sounds interesting. Could you elaborate this technique in an answer?

Comment: Anyway, I don't think that missing include is the most important and dangerous problem for portability. it is easy to (partially) fix on problematic platform once encountered.

Comment: "… and this is common in practice." - I hope not. At least in a professional project team. (which is not the same as "they are paid for their work").

Comment: Forgetting to `#include` a header **is** a programming error. A static code analyser tool might help, but we are not a recommendation site.

Comment: Yes I agree it's a programming error. Looking for compiler  or other help to detect it. Doesn't have to be a recommendation for a tool.

Comment: @Olag "by this is common in practice" I mean that it is common for different standard library implementations to include different sets of headers (not that relying accidentally relying on indirect includes was common - but I certainly believe that happens somewhat often as well, professional project or otherwise).

Comment: @BeeOnRope _"I mean that it is common for different standard library implementations to include different sets of headers "_ Nope! That's your misconception. The commonly adopted consensus is that you include **every header necessary** for what you're going to use in your code. What's so hard to grasp about that actually? Elaborate that in your question please!

Comment: @Olaf: I think that the missing correct include happens more often than it should but that error is easily spotted when compiling for a new target and is easy to fix. And that happen less often when compiling for different target. That functionality would be a good complement to tools like [include-what-you-use](https://include-what-you-use.org/)

Comment: @Jarod42: I did not say it never happens, but - as you wrote - it is nothing one should put any effort in cathing in advance, but conceptrate on writing correct code instead. After all, it is a bug to be fixed. Not worth spending a single more thought.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know existing tools which does it.

But a way to do it would be to construct (That a huge task) all the *"fake"* headers with only standard declarations. (function definitions should not be required, but class definition would be).

For some headers, you can find pages which provide `Synopsis` that you can use mostly directly as for [cstddef](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstddef):

```
namespace std {
    using ptrdiff_t = /*see definition*/ ;
    using size_t = /*see definition*/ ;
    using max_align_t = /*see definition*/ ;
    using nullptr_t = decltype(nullptr);

    enum class byte : unsigned char {} ;
    template <class IntegerType>
    constexpr byte& operator<<=(byte& b, IntegerType shift) noexcept;
    template <class IntegerType>
    constexpr byte operator<<(byte b, IntegerType shift) noexcept;
    template <class IntegerType>
    constexpr byte& operator>>=(byte& b, IntegerType shift) noexcept;
    template <class IntegerType>
    constexpr byte operator>>(byte b, IntegerType shift) noexcept;

    constexpr byte& operator|=(byte& l, byte r) noexcept;
    constexpr byte operator|(byte l, byte r) noexcept;
    constexpr byte& operator&=(byte& l, byte r) noexcept;
    constexpr byte operator&(byte l, byte r) noexcept;
    constexpr byte& operator^=(byte& l, byte r) noexcept;
    constexpr byte operator^(byte l, byte r) noexcept;
    constexpr byte operator~(byte b) noexcept;
    template <class IntegerType>
    constexpr IntegerType to_integer(byte b) noexcept; 
}
#define NULL /*see definition*/
#define offsetof(P, D) /*see definition*/
```

Others header would be more complicated to fake :-/

Then, (The easy part) in your build chain, you substitute the real standard headers by your fake ones. Something like:

- `g++ -nostdinc -I/path/to/fake/headers`
- `/X` (Ignore Standard Include Paths) and `/I` (Additional Include Directories) parameters for visual.

As you don't provide definitions, you will finally have linker errors.

But, before, if you forget to add a required include, you should have a compiler error due to the missing declaration.

Comment: But the fake headers would essentially have to reproduce a large amount of the functionality of the standard library. Sure you can leave the actual implementations blank, but a huge part of the standard library is all the template stuff which must at least be fleshed out enough for everything to compile.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, template class require more works than simple function. (and don't provide implementation instead of leaving it blank should be better).

Comment: So you recommend use your own headers basically? What about implemen tation-specific extensions? gcc for instance provides macros with the ranges of the standard integer types. Or `inline` methods/functions? Functions defined as macros, etc.? I might be wrong, but to me that looks like a terrible idea.

Comment: @Jarod42 We're getting downvotes all the way?? I don't get it :-P Seems there are a lot of idiots are around.

Comment: @Jarod42 What a tremendous effort to solve such a simple (non) problem. It seems it's mostly the OP's laziness is causing _"the problem"_ at all.